# Embedded config file in fat jar isn't recognised while running under docker

Tags: docker, spring-boot, axis

We have a spring-boot application with axis JAX-RPC service exposed (legacy system need to support it in the new world for some time). While the fat jar build works as intended when running as a standalone app on a laptop. If I embed the jar into docker image, I'm getting the following error during run time:

```
2018-02-12 14:34:46.011 ERROR [api-jva-pricing-,,,] 7 --- [nio-9510-exec-1] .a.a.c.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet : Problem with servlet engine /WEB-INF directory
org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: Configuration file directory '/tmp/tomcat-docbase.682267175490034491.9510/WEB-INF' does not exist or is not a directory or is not readable.
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.<init>(FileProvider.java:99) ~[axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.getServerEngineConfig(EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.java:174) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.getServerEngineConfig(EngineConfigurationFactoryServlet.java:99) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngineEnvironment(AxisServletBase.java:273) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:172) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:156) [axis-1.4.jar!/:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:795) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar!/:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
```

The file, axis is sturggling to find is in fat jar at location `/WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd`. Above issue is seen only when being run in docker container. As anyone come across issue like this?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, here is the solution that worked for me. As mentioned I was seeing this issue only when I had fat jar being run from the docker container. I had not seen the problem when run locally on my laptop using the fat jar with the same command as docker container. A solution is to explode the jar and start the docker entrypoint with one of the Spring Boot Launcher class relevant to your target. See here for details - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html section Exploded archives.

Comment: It would be interesting to know from docker experts or spring-boot experts if there are any resource constraints to running fat-jar in docker.